# Need to ingest snappy avro files to ADX (Kusto)

Tags: avro, azure-data-explorer, snappy

Any recommendation for a workflow/serverless solution decompressing the avro files before ingestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify "apacheavro" format that supports avro with snappy encoding